# Share data between "request scope" and HttpMessageHandler without HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am using IHttpClientFactory and want to share ("request-")scoped data with a custom HttpMessageHandler.
As MessageHandlers maintain their own lifecycle (they are shared across HttpClients and expire after 2mins, and especially run in their own DI scope, see [this blogpost here](https://andrewlock.net/understanding-scopes-with-ihttpclientfactory-message-handlers/)), I cannot use a scoped service to share data.

The usual workaround is to use HttpContext and either store data in the Items property or access the IServiceProvider of the request scope via HttpContext.RequestServices property.

In my case this is not working as I am working with a framework build by a colleague which lets you work with ServiceBus events just like you are used to work with REST calls in .NET core: It will create scopes and execute workers for incoming requests, you get an EventContext etc...
But: There is no resemblance of IHttpContextAccessor...
That means I cannot rely on something like HttpContext in my custom HttpMessageHandler for pulling event scoped data...

The concrete use case here is:
A inbound correlation id from a service bus event should be transparently attached to outbound HttpClient calls as a header...

Comment: After playing around a bit, it looks like extending the framework with something like HttpContextAccessor, making use of AsyncLocal, looks promising.

[src HttpContextAccessor](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/HttpContextAccessor.cs)